# Package an .so, that is already contained in an aar, into an apk

Tags: android, apk, aar, .so

I have a 3rd party aar file which contains some .so files. But when assembling my apk, the .so is not packaged into the apk. How to package  the .so into an apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the reason why the so files were not packaged into the apk.

aar file struct should be like this:

```
/AndroidManifest.xml (mandatory)
/classes.jar (mandatory)
/res/ (mandatory)
/R.txt (mandatory)
/assets/ (optional)
/libs/*.jar (optional)
/jni/<abi>/*.so (optional)
/proguard.txt (optional)
/lint.jar (optional)
```

but my aar file struct :

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── R.txt
├── assets
├── classes.jar
├── libs
│   ├── arm64-v8a
│   ├── armeabi
│   ├── armeabi-v7a
│   ├── x86
│   └── x86_64
└── res
```

the so file were placed in the wrong place。

at last, i repackage the aar, Everything is OK.